# Ethernet cable not detected after force shutdown in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, ethernet, network-bridge

[image]My Ubuntu 18.04 shutdown forcefully because of a power outage.

Now after restart, I have two new accounts

- dnetmaster
- netplan daemon user

In my user profile, the internet does not work.

After reading a few suggestions I activated the network-manager.

But, still my Ethernet card is not being detected.
What could be the reason for the above behavior and how can I debug it?

Tried `sudo lshw -C network`

Here i get `*network disabled`

Comment: What's the ouptut of the command `ip addr show`?

Comment: @guillermochamorro I have two interfaces `eno1` and `lo` which I assume is the localhost and the MAC interface. I am missing the `eth0` interface

Comment: @user68186 have put the snapshot could not copy paste it.

Comment: eno1 is your ethernet interface.

Comment: @chili555 the ../70-persistent file which auto generates after reboot is not present, how can I correct this? also how can I change to the default mappings or names.

Comment: @user68186 the problem is it is on another machine and it does not have internet on, hence cannot paste it here

Comment: eno1 is consistent with the default naming scheme for 18.04. The creation of persistent files to rename interfaces is a dead-end attempt to use the old methods. We no longer use wooden wheels on our sleek black BMWs.

Comment: @chili555 so eno1 is the default scheme, but any clues on why my internet is not working?
also why was two accounts created on force power shutdown'

Comment: Does this say that interfaces are managed by NM? `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep eno1` Or here? `cat /etc/network/interfaces` Or here? `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Please paste the result of all of those here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96535/discussion-between-abhilash-gopalakrishna-and-chili555).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the above suggestions in the comment and some research I got a solution for the above.

**What worked:**

Manually updating the /etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

**Why I believe it works:**[Just my understanding]

Because of the force shutdown, netplan has been created as a new user account.
Therefore, netplan in the user account is not able to update the

> /etc/networking/interfaces

file with the new Ethernet interface mappings.

Will update the answer as I learn more